# an Example of Elliptic Curve over finite field has no CM

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

I have known this property (from Silverman's *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*): Let $\operatorname{char}(K)=p>0,$ and let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve with $j(E)~
\overline{\in}~ \overline{ \mathbb{F}}_{p}$, then $\operatorname{End}(E)=\mathbb{Z}$.

I want to see an example when  $\operatorname{End}(E)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Thank you.

Comment: What is $\bar{\in}$? Do you mean $\not\in$? In that case, there is no example, because the $j$-invariant of a curve defined over $K$ is always in $K$.

Comment: @ Hurkyl You are right. But I still confused by the purpose of the above property, which is the exercise 5.8 in Silverman's book.

Comment: But $K$ is not necessarily $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$.

Comment: ... e.g. you might have a curve defined over the function field $K = \mathbf{F}_p(x)$, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elliptic curves with $j$-invariant lying in a finite field (or equivalently,
in the algebraic closure of a finite field) always admit endomorphisms other
than $\mathbb Z$.